# Items not displayed on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, display

It is been a long time that I am trying to solve my problem but I dont find solution.

I am just trying to show on my app a simple text. On android studio I see the text but not on my device. And obviously , I dont know why ..
Here the diferents codes and screen.

```
ImageView image_edt;
TextView texte;
URL urlWelcome;
@Override
//public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistantState){
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    texte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_edt);
    texte.setText("erreur internet");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

the xml :

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/text_edt"
   android:layout_width="361dp"
   android:layout_height="79dp"
   android:background="@android:color/black"
   android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
   app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.066" />
```

and the sceen:
[screen of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbLLG.png)

Comment: first of all, remove the second call of `setContentView()`....and second, are you sure that the colors black and background_light are configured correctly? Different html color code?

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct name of the xml file in the class `setContentView` and remove the second call of the setContentView

Comment: Thanks, I will try tomorrow jour solution . Have a Nice end of day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling setContentView() method twice. The one call after setting text of the text view, replaces the current layout which removes all the modifications you made to your layout.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    texte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_edt);
    texte.setText("erreur internet");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  // remove this line and it should fix your problem
}
```